# xdmp:document-load throws XDMP-DOCDUPATTR for malformed html document, even with repair=full

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I used this expression to load an html document:

```
xdmp:document-load("http://example.com/index.html",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load" xmlns:http="xdmp:http">
    <uri>/documents/content.xml</uri>
    <repair>full</repair>
    <format>xml</format>
</options>
```

The `repair` `full` option works well with unclosed tags. But one of the tags has two attributes with the same name, and this causes an error `XDMP-DOCDUPATTR`.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4):

You can try getting the document as text and then applying tidy -- there's an example at the end of:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:tidy

Hoping that helps

Comment: http://markmail.org/message/effny6kxqmgop7zf might be useful too. It discusses how to structure this kind of thing so that you only fetch the document once, then try a series of processing steps on the response.

Answer (score 1):

You could also load HTML documents as flat text: `<format>text</format>` instead of `<format>xml</format>`. The document will be a single text node. All the HTML will be preserved, but there will be no XML structure so XPath won't be useful.